# List of selects, with an ability to remove them, and add a child select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a pretty vague question, but please bear with me.

I am using React to create a component, which takes in an object containing keys and values as a prop. Each value is a list of values. This component should provide a button to create a select containing the provided object's keys and also create a button that can remove the said select and itself. I should be able to create an arbitrary amount of selects.

When any of the selects has a change, it should create another select by it's side that contains the list of values corresponding to the parent select's selected key. I should then be able to form a key-value-pairs out of the parent selects' keys and the childs' values.

My question is how do I keep references to everything? The delete button has to remove just the select it was created with and also the child select. I have played around with adding things to an array, where these components could be pretty easy to push and pop, but then the delete button has to know it's position in the array and then also update the position of the other ones too. And also the selects need to know about each other.

I am confused and don't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each delete-select pair should be a separate component (e.g. `SelectField`), something like this:

```
class SelectFields extends Component {
  _handleDelete = (selectToRemove) => {
    this.setState({
      fields: this.state.fields.filter(select => select !== selectToRemove)
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.selects.map(select => <SelectField data={select} onDelete={this._handleDelete.bind(this, select)}/>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Eventually went this way, I created a separate component for each row of selects and delete buttons.